# 'dd' command on Damn Small Linux?

Tags: command-line, shell, dd, imaging, damn-small-linux

I looked at the package list of DSL, and I don't see 'dd'. For example I would like to restore `/dev/sdb` from an .img file like so:

```
dd bs=1M if=/home/myname/image.img of=/dev/sdb
```

What command do I use in DSL for this? Or is there a 'dd' command built in? Because it's not on the package list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
I just installed it to confirm but dd is installed with the default installation of DSL. The following only applies if you've somehow removed it (if that is the case then you may have a lot of other important stuff missing too, you may be better off starting fresh too because this could be really difficult to fix manually.

--

Open a terminal. At the prompt, type the following:

```
wget http://distro.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/distributions/damnsmall/mydsl/gnu-utils.dsl
```

This will download the `gnu-utils.dsl` file onto `/home/dsl`.  If this did not work, your problem is probably your internet connection.  Check if the file was downloaded properly by confirming that its size is around 1.2 MB ( `ls -lh ~/gnu-utils.dsl` ).

Then at the prompt, type the following:

```
mydsl-load gnu-utils.dsl
```

This will load the extension.  Check this by executing the following command:

```
dd --help
```

If everything is working you can delete `~/gnu-utils.dsl`.

A full listing of programs which can be installed this way is on the DSL site: http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/mydsl/system/

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that DSL does have dd, it just isnt listed on the package list.